# Wilkinson's polynomial very simple misunderstanding

Tags: numerical-methods, condition-number

The Wilkinson polynomial $W(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{20}(x-k)$ is notoriously ill conditioned.

I wanted to play around with it and see for myself. I wrote a computer code that does bisection method.

I gave the code the interval $[a,b] = [19.2, 20.9]$ and told it to run for 5 iterations or so.

The real root is $r = 20$. The approximate root I got was $r_a \approx 20.23$, hence the forward error is $|r-r_a| = |20-20.23| = 0.23$

The backward error is $|W(r) - W(r_a)| = |W(r_a)| \approx 3 \cdot 10^{12}$ if I read that huge number correctly.

So the error magnification is $\frac{\text{forward}}{\text{backward}} = \frac{0.23}{ 3 \cdot 10^{12}} = {}$very tiny number.

Doesn't this imply that the problem is well conditioned? I got something mixed up

Comment: Are you sure that your forward and backward errors aren't reversed?  Forward error is often in the codomain and backwards error is in the domain.

Comment: As far as I know, the forward error is the distance from the actual root, and the backward error is what problem we actually solved (which is "find root of $W(r) - W(r_a)$)

Comment: How did you evaluate the function, what numerical data type? In float 64 bit I get as the midpoint of the 5th interval `20.0234375` with a value of `3094032481825792.0`. The opposite point is `19.996875` with a negative value `-375235002409472.0`. The algorithm proceeds to the interval `[20.0000275, 20.0000283]` which is relatively far away from your root approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your computer can hold the *exact* coefficients of the polynomial, you will be able to get some sort of stability in calculating the roots, even with such a crude method as interval bisection. However, this isn't the point of Wilkinson's polynomial. Rather, what the polynomial demonstrates is that a tiny error in the *data* for a problem, namely in the *coefficients* of the polynomial, can lead to a big error in the solution values (the roots). A consequence of this, for example, would be big errors in obtaining the eigenvalues of a matrix by calculating the roots of its characteristic polynomial, where the matrix entries may not be exact even though specified to pretty good precision.

Wilkinson's polynomial is ill conditioned because of the huge ratio of the error in the solution to an error in the data. The ratio you cite is another matter.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that statement. After all, when solving for roots using an approximate method, I already am getting a root for a perturbed problem. The output of the algorithm is an approximate root of Wilkinson, but it is an exact root of some perturbation of Wilkinson.